# TSQL Split XML attributes

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have an xml string and need to manipulate it within sql.

```
<RuleData ReturnVariable="">
  <MateProperties>
    <Property Key="value" DisplayName="name value" />
    <Property Key="value2" DisplayName="name value2" />
  </MateProperties>
  <ReferenceNames>
    <Item Name="0" Value="=CouplerType + &quot;-1&quot;" />
    <Item Name="1" Value="Driveshaft-1" />
  </ReferenceNames>
  <ReferenceFeatures>
    *<Item Name="=CouplerType + &quot;-1&quot;" Value="CSYS_BOREB" />
    <Item Name="Driveshaft-1" Value="CSYS_CouplerINSIDE" />*
  </ReferenceFeatures>
</RuleData>
```

These two lines I need to convert them.

```
<Item Name="=CouplerType + &quot;-1&quot;" Value="CSYS_BOREB" />
<Item Name="Driveshaft-1" Value="CSYS_CouplerINSIDE" />
```

To This new format.

```
<Value>
  <Column Value="=CouplerType + &quot;" />
  <Column Value="CSYS_BOREB" />
</Value>
<Value>
  <Column Value="Driveshaft-1" />
  <Column Value="CSYS_CouplerINSIDE" />
</Value>
```

Essentially each line has to be split in two and re-named. I Can take care of the re-naming i just am having trouble splitting the columns. I have to do exactly the same thing in the ReferenceNames Section as well. That one is easier as Its always "0" and "1" so i can simply convert the xml to string and find replace with that. The ReferenceFeatures section though is more complicated because anything can be in the name section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml =
    N'<RuleData>
        <ReferenceFeatures>
            <Item Name="=CouplerType + &quot;-1&quot;" Value="CSYS_BOREB" />
            <Item Name="Driveshaft-1" Value="CSYS_CouplerINSIDE" />
        </ReferenceFeatures>
    </RuleData>'

;with items as
(
    select
        row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as RowNumber
        ,t.n.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(255)') as Name
        ,t.n.value('@Value', 'nvarchar(255)') as Value
    from @xml.nodes('//RuleData/ReferenceFeatures/Item') as t(n)
)
select
    (select it.Name as [@Value] for xml path ('Column'), type),
    (select it.Value as [@Value] for xml path ('Column'), type)
from items it
order by it.RowNumber
for xml raw ('Value'), type
```